# jquery.serialScroll-1.2.1.js edit in Coda Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

Coda Slider:

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-slider-effect/

I recently implemented the Coda Slider on my webpage but I came across one issue. What the issue more like a implementation, I was wondering about is, change/disable the left button if the user is on the first slide and change/disable the right button if the user is on the right slide. User cannot press the left button to go to the last slide and the right button to scroll all the way to the first slide. I would like to disable that feature.

I tried to look at the code and see where I would have to change or add the code to but was unable to determine. Can anyone please help?

Example:
I have four slides (0-3) What code would I add so the left button (id=leftb) is hidden when I scroll to slides 0 and the right button (id=rightb) is hidden when I scroll to slide 3. I added the following code:

```
if (n<0) { //if on first slide make left button hidden and right button visible
if (document.getElementById) { 
document.getElementById('leftb').style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
document.getElementById('rightb').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
}}
if (n==0 || n==1 || n ==2) { //if on second and third slides make both button visible
if (document.getElementById) { 
document.getElementById('leftb').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
document.getElementById('rightb').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
}}

if (n>2) { //if on last slide make right button hidden and left button visible
if (document.getElementById) { 
document.getElementById('leftb').style.visibility = 'visible'; 
document.getElementById('rightb').style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
}}
```

The above code i think makes sense in terms hiding and showing the navigation button based on the slide number but it's not working.

Any idea?

***EDIT:***

The files version i currently have are:

- jquery-1.2.6.js
- jquery.easing.1.3.js
- jquery.localscroll-1.2.5.js
- jquery.scrollTo-1.3.3.js
- jquery.serialScroll-1.2.1.js
- coda-slider.js

Which files am i downloading from the github and update ony my server for it to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've forked serialScroll to add this feature. You now have a 'wrap' option that you can set to false to disable. You can check my commit on github to see the details:

https://github.com/lperrin/jquery.serialScroll

Basically, I added `checkDisableWrap`:

```
function checkDisableControls( pos, limit ){
  $(settings.prev).css('visibility', pos <= 0 ? 'hidden' : 'visible');
  $(settings.next).css('visibility', pos >= limit ? 'hidden' : 'visible');
};
```

Which is triggered every time the plugin scrolls.

Comment: I downloaded the .JS file and overwrote the current one and uploaded and i get an error in line 201 "Object does not support property"

Comment: I've just checked that the demo included in the plugin project worked. Do you have a live website that I can debug ?

Comment: The github version of serialScroll is using a newer version of scrollTo. You have to update this plugin as well.

Comment: I downloaded both Serialscroll and scrollTo JS file and the images are still not doing what is suppose to do.

Comment: You need to pass the option 'wrap: false' to serialScroll. It's defined in coda-slider.js at line 89.

Comment: i think wrap:false and cycle:false both resolves the continuous scroll. Thanks

Comment: How do i achieve the hiding the arrow based on the slides the user is in? Because if they can't scroll anymore to the left past the 0 slide no point in showing that arrow and vice versa for the right arrow past the 3rd slide. makes sense?

Comment: The arrow hides, but only after you interact with the slider. You should add "img.left { visibility: hidden; }" to your CSS so that the left arrow is initially hidden.

Comment: You know what, i do not know how to THANK YOU enough for working through this issue with me! i GREATLY appreciate all your help. Keep up the great work. it WORKS!!!!!! :)

Comment: one last question now i am running into is, how do i reset the page to default setting on page refresh?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15137/discussion-between-laurent-perrin-and-interfaith)